# filter: alpha in javascript syntax

Tags: javascript

If I'm changing opacity via CSS I use two versions:

```
opacity: 1;
filter: alpha(opacity=100); /*IE8 & earlier*/
```

If I'm changing opacity via javascript, I know this version:

```
object.style.opacity="xx"
```

which I believe I can also prefix with -webkit-, -moz-, and -o-, but is there a javascript equivalent for filter: alpha(opacity) or does style.opacity cover IE8 & earlier? I am not using JQuery or any other libraries, just javascript and CSS.

Thanks

Comment: using javascript is just still based on CSS features. So if the CSS features are not supported, using something like `style.feature = ...` will also not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try adding::

```
object.style.opacity = someValue;
object.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + someValue + ')';
```

See [Opacity Setting](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/opacity.html) for reference